# Connect and Mount Multiple Google Drive Account with Google Colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

**Original Colab Code :** https://colab.research.google.com/github/arenasys/qDiffusion/blob/master/remote_colab.ipynb

**GitHub :** https://github.com/arenasys/qDiffusion

The Original Code mount in One Google Drive account. I want to connect multiple different Google Drive account and mount it. So, it take `Models (Files)` from both Google Drive account.

**I am trying :** Please refer the original code to better understand what i changed myself here.

```
%cd /content
import IPython.display
import os
import sys

if not os.path.exists("/content/sd-inference-server"):
    !git clone https://github.com/arenasys/sd-inference-server.git

%cd /content/sd-inference-server
model_folder = "/content/sd-inference-server/models"

def mount_drive(drive_folder):
    try:
        from google.colab import drive
        drive.mount(drive_folder, force_remount=True)
        model_folder = os.path.join(drive_folder, "qDiffusion/models")
        if not os.path.exists(model_folder):
            !mkdir -p "{model_folder}"
            !cp -r 'models/' "{model_folder}/"
        return model_folder
    except Exception as e:
        return None

drive_accounts = []
num_accounts = int(input("Enter the number of Google Drive accounts to link: "))
for i in range(num_accounts):
    drive_folder = f"/content/drive"
    print(f"Linking Google Drive account {i+1}...")
    model_folder = mount_drive(drive_folder)
    if model_folder:
        drive_accounts.append(model_folder)
        print(f"Linked Google Drive account {i+1} successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to link Google Drive account {i+1}.")

if not drive_accounts:
    print("No Google Drive accounts linked. Using default model_folder.")

if not os.path.exists("venv"):
    !curl -OJL https://huggingface.co/datasets/arenasys/qDiffusion/resolve/main/cached_venv5.tar
    !tar xf cached_venv5.tar; mv cached_venv5 venv; rm cached_venv5.tar
    !rm /content/sd-inference-server/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pathlib.py
    !pip install timm==0.6.13
    !pip install tomesd==0.1.3
    !pip install torchmetrics
    !pip uninstall -y tensorflow

    !wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/367274644/libgoogle-perftools-dev_2.5-2.2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
    !wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/google-perftools/2.5-2.2ubuntu3/+build/14795286/+files/google-perftools_2.5-2.2ubuntu3_all.deb
    !wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/google-perftools/2.5-2.2ubuntu3/+build/14795286/+files/libtcmalloc-minimal4_2.5-2.2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
    !wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/google-perftools/2.5-2.2ubuntu3/+build/14795286/+files/libgoogle-perftools4_2.5-2.2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
    !apt install -qq libunwind8-dev
    !dpkg -i *.deb
    %env LD_PRELOAD=libtcmalloc.so

    IPython.display.clear_output()

if not sys.path[0] == "/content/sd-inference-server/":
    sys.path.insert(0, "/content/sd-inference-server/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages")
    sys.path.insert(0, "/content/sd-inference-server/")

from pycloudflared import try_cloudflare
tunnel_url = try_cloudflare(port=28888, verbose=False)
print("ENDPOINT:", tunnel_url.tunnel.replace("https", "wss"))

for account_num, account_folder in enumerate(drive_accounts):
    print(f"Running remote.py for Google Drive account {account_num+1}")
    model_folder = mount_drive(account_folder)
    if model_folder:
        !python remote.py "{model_folder}"
    else:
        print(f"Failed to run remote.py for Google Drive account {account_num+1}.")

try_cloudflare.terminate(28888)
```

**Problems :**

1. Pop Up is not opening to connect Google Drive Account
2. Not creating functional Endpoint and Password